# Selenium IDE - Can I have a custom field value?

Tags: ide, selenium

With Selenium IDE, I can tell a field to input a certain value. However I need to test a form on a daily basis with at least one piece of unique information. This goes across probably 40 forms. In selenium IDE, it will allow you to change the field, but is there a way to make the email be "5142019@test.com" and it update the numbers everyday depending on the date?

[I basically need this "Value" field to be able to self populate based on the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkC1q.png)

Comment: Assuming you're using the Chrome extension, if you right click the extension icon, are you able to click on `Options`?

Comment: No I am not able to. It's grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, you can dynamically generate data with the Selenium IDE extension.

To do this, you need to add an `execute script` command into your test.

To insert a new command into your existing test, just right click on any of the commands, and select `Insert new command`. From there, you can drag and drop the command where you need it to be. In your code, you'll want the place the new command between the `click` on line 23 and the `type` on line 24.

The new command will just be a line with a comment `//` at first. Click on the commented line to begin editing the new command.

The `execute script` looks like this:

[image]

Here's the `Target` in text so you can copy and paste it:

```
return "test" + new Date().valueOf() + "@gmail.com";
```

If you want a value that looks like a meaningful date, like in your screenshot, use this for the `Target` instead:

```
return "test" + (new Date().getUTCMonth()+1) + new Date().getUTCDate() + new Date().getUTCFullYear() + new Date().getUTCHours() + new Date().getUTCMinutes() + new Date().getUTCSeconds() + new Date().getUTCMilliseconds() + "@gmail.com";
```

Once you have added the `execute script` command, you just need to modify the `type` command that is on line 24. Instead of the `Value` being *test5142019@gmail.com* you'll need to change the `Value` to `${email}` so it refers to the value that was created with the `execute script` command.

Comment: DrZoo - this is BEYOND helpful! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this. It works 100% and I couldn't be happier!

Comment: @ConstellationQA you're welcome! Being a new user, if an answer solves your problem, it's best to mark it as an answer. If a future user searches for this, or something similar, they can see from the search page that the question has been answered with a solution that solved the problem.

Comment: Did I do it right? I think so!

Comment: @ConstellationQA yeah you got it correct. Just remember that for any future questions you might ask on any Stack Exchange network. Although you don't have to mark an answer if one of the provided answers doesn't solve your problem.